# What is the best way to implement search on my site using google search?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a simple site for local student contest. I want to implement some **basic search functionality** (just a textbox with submitButton or submitLink).
 The site contains several pages with static informational content there, and  one google-forms iframe(register for the event).

Is it a good idea to implement my search with javascript which redirects user to something like 
http://www.google.ru/search?q=BLAH+BLAH+site:mysite.com ?

The less code, the better. Server-side code would not be great, but still ok.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Google Custom Search Engine: http://www.google.com/cse/

It's extremely simple to set up, basically it's just a matter of copy pasting and as far as I understand, it will give you exactly what you want.